# CSS: Multi-color footer background issue

Tags: css

I having difficulties setting my footer properly. I have a Bottom navigation bar as part of my footer which is working fine(color:#7A7A7A). The issue is with the copy right information that follows. It has an address and phone number. I am wanting that this  side of the footer to have a black bakcground(#000). This part is labeled in the css under copyRight which i am not get any results.  Any Ideas of what may be wrong?

Here is my [Live EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test/).
Thank you

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
    background:#333333;
    font-family: trebuchet, 'trebuchet ms', 'tahoma', sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    color:#5e5e5e;
    line-height: 130%;
}


/****** COLORBLOCK: this is the orangey-yellow bar behind the wrapper in the background. ******/

#colorblock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #c69a55;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/**************************************************/



div#container {
    position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
    width:925px;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */
    border-right: 15px solid #000000;
    border-left: 15px solid #000000;

}

div#contentArea {
    padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */

}
    div#contentArea p {
        text-align:justify;
        padding:0 1em;
    }

#content {
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    background: #ebebeb;
    padding: 5px;
    width:635px;
    height: 400px;

}

/****** TOP BANNER: This is the banner with Greg's List logo and main navigation. Also includes the styles for the main navigation links. ******/
div#header {
    /*padding:1em;*/
    height: 175px;
    border-top:15px solid #000000;

}
    div#header p {
        margin:0;
    }



/****** LEFT COLUMN: This is the left gray column next to the content. Features the styling for the log-in form and the location links. ******/

#left2 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background: #dddddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 400px;
}


/****** FOOTER: This is the junk at the bottom of the page. Do NOT remove the clear div; it's what makes it stick to the bottom. ******/


div#footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0; /* stick to bottom */
    background:#7A7A7A;
    border-bottom:15px solid #000000;
}
    div#footer p {
        padding:1em;
        margin:0;
    }

a.footer {
    color: #c7c7c7;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}   


p { 
    margin:0 0 1em;
}   

#copyRight{
 background:#000;   
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 75%;
 bottom: 0;


}

.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}



</style>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're floating the contents of #copyRight so it needs to be floated in order to contain them properly. Add this to #copyRight:

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

[Read Brilliand detailed explanation below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11240702/527775)

Comment: There are many ways to contain floats; I favor `overflow: hidden`, myself.

Comment: Combination of both (Telemanko and Ahsan) is working http://jsfiddle.net/Az2JA/1/

Comment: @barts - Using both is redundant.  But anyhow, `overflow-hidden` doesn't do anything; you need `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @Brilliand May I ask why you do prefer `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: @Brilliand: Bang.. I need more coffee. Thanks for pointing out http://jsfiddle.net/Az2JA/2/

Comment: `overflow: hidden` doesn't require an explicit width, for one thing - `width: auto` is frequently needed for unrelated reasons.  Also, `float: left` specifically could cause the parent element to stick out of its container, forcing you to float everything clear up to the main wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` in  `#copyRight`

So your CSS should look like this:

```
#copyRight{
    background:#000;   
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 75%;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that most elements, including divs, do not by default expand to contain floating elements.  Since everything within `copyRight` is floating, it behaves as though it were empty, and shrinks to nothing.

There are many ways to make an element expand to contain floating elements.  My personal favorite is to set `overflow` to just about anything - `hidden` being the most common.

```
#copyRight{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Another way is to make the containing element float too, though it's then liable to cause the same problem with the element trying to contain it.  Also, floating causes shrinkwrapping, so you have to set an explicit width:

```
#copyRight{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

A similar result can be achieved using various `display` declarations, such as `display: inline-block`.  This avoids propagating the problem to the parent element:

```
#copyRight{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Apparently back in 2004 it was considered a wonderful new idea to solve such a problem by [inserting a clearing element with the `:after` pseudo-class](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html/) instead of the older method of adding a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`.  Those tricks would also solve your problem, though clearing floats and containing them are not quite the same thing.

Comment: `overflow: auto` could possibly be better than `overflow: hidden`, depending on whether scrollbars would be a good fallback in a pathological edge case (user stylesheet sets font to 52pt?).  The difference is very small, though.

Comment: I linked to this reply on my accepted solution. Thanks for the detailed explanation.